# What does the log really say

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have been trying to understand what MarkLogic is trying to tell me in the ErrorLog.txt log file.

This one, for example. You may read that element `id` for namespace `http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi/object` and with collation `http://marklogic.com/collation/` does not exist, but that is not true, it is there, quadruple checked it.

> 16/04/07 13:12:56 ERROR mapreduce.ContentWriter: XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND: cts:search(fn:collection("http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi/revision"), cts:and-query((cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("obj:id"), "=", "06b7d2a0-c5b0-4a91-8886-368673805c42", ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/"), 1), cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("http://dikw.nl/dikw/vriend/incident","external-id"), "162110", ("lang=en"), 1), cts:not-query(cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("source:id"), "=", "85a0aa8c-7495-4d0f-8f97-8a009e57306a", ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/"), 1), 1)), ())) -- No string element range index for {http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi/object}id http://marklogic.com/collation/

What is it that MarkLogic is telling me here?

Answer (score 3):

This is the essential bit of the message (the last bit):

> No string element range index for
>   {http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi/object}id
>   http://marklogic.com/collation/

So, apparently it is looking for an element range index of type `string`, for an element named `id` in namespace `http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi/object`, and the index should have root collation.

Is it possible that either the index exists, but with codepoint collation, or there is a reindex going on, and the content hasn't been fully indexed yet?

HTH!

Comment: Apparently, the XDBC app-server had default collation `http://marklogic.com/collation/` and it should have been `http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint`. I've changed the ROXY config from default XDBC to this collation, re-bootstrapped and now it's working.

Comment: You could also argue, that code should not depend on odd defaults. I'd reach out to the builder if I were you.. ;)